# Prove that $I_A$ is a random variable with $A$ being the union of events $B$ $\in$ $\mathbb{F}$ such that $0 < P(B) < 1$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

> Let $(\Omega, \mathbb{F}, P)$ be a probability space. Prove that $I_A$ is a random variable with $A$ being the union of events $B$ $\in$ $\mathbb{F}$ such that  $0$ $<$ $P(B)$ $<$  $1$.

My doubt is about the question above. I know that a random variable is a function $X: \Omega \longrightarrow \Re$ and that I need $X^{-1}(I)$ $\in$ $\mathbb{F}$, $\forall$ $I \subset \Re$, but I don't have idea how prove this, because I never saw a question about proof in probability until the moment.

Comment: $I_A$ is a random variable if and only if $A$ is an event. Is your $A$ an event?

Comment: You do not need $X^{-1}(I)\in\mathbb{F}$ for all $I\subset\mathfrak{R}$; that is too strong. Checking a family of generating sets is sufficient (e.g. for all $I$ open). Regardless, Did points out an equivalent characterization for indicator variables above.

Comment: @par, this is the definition in my book of probability.

Comment: @Did, if A is a countable union, yes, because $\mathbb{F}$ is a $\sigma - algebra$ and A is a union of $B$ $\in$ $\mathbb{F}$, but if A is a uncountable union, how can I prove that A is an event or can I claim that A is a countable union?

Comment: What happens is that $A$ is (nearly) always the same set... Hint: If $B$ is an event such that $0<P(B)<1$ then so is $B^c$ and $B\cup B^c=$ $____$ hence...

Comment: Hint: As @Did pointed out, can you confirm that $A\in \mathbb{F}$?

Comment: Does the question means that $A$ is the union of ALL events $B\in\mathbb{F}$ such that  $0<P(B)<1$?  Or $A$ is the union of SOME events $B\in\mathbb{F}$ such that  $0<P(B)<1$?

Comment: @Did, Is this?

$B \cup B^C = \Omega$ hence $\cup_{B \subset A} (B \cup B^C) =$ $(\cup_{B \subset A} B)$ $\cup$ $(\cup_{B \subset A} B^C) =$ $(A)$ $\cup$ $(\cup_{B \subset A} B^C)$, so $A = \cup_{B \subset A} (B \cup B^C) - (\cup_{B \subset A} B^C)$ = $\Omega - (\cup_{B \subset A} B^C) = \Omega$ $\cup$ $(\cap_{B \subset A} B)$

$\Omega, (\cap_{B \subset A} B) \in \mathbb{F}$, so $A \in \mathbb{F}$

Comment: If at least one $B$ in $F$ with $0<P(B)<1$ exists then $0<P(B^c)<1$ and $B^c$ is in $F$ hence $A\supseteq B\cup B^c=\Omega$ hence $A=\Omega$ and $A$ is in $F$. If no $B$ in $F$ with $0<P(B)<1$ exists then...

Comment: @Did, I understood, thanks!